# Selecting a single value using linq if already duplicate values exist in mvc4

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have a table

```
    public class Product
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model_Name { get; set; }
    public string Company_Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Price { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
```

Now the table contains multipe items so I just want to retrive the name of the company  and dispay it. However the column Company_Name contains duplicate values. How do I need to check if it contains duplicate names then also display the value only once.I want to check it within view. Here is the View.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>                   
         //Anything extra could be added here to check the duplicate values
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Company_Name, "Brand", 
         new { Company_Name = item.Company_Name })
    </td>  
</tr
 } 
  Here is how the table looks like
 Id           Model_Name          Company_Name            price          photo
  1           S7862                Samsung                1500           something
  2           Galaxy               Samsung                1500           something
  3           Apple                Apple                  2000           something
  4           Desire               HTC                    1500           something
  5           Desire X2            HTC                    1500           something
  6           Nokia Lumia          Nokia                   1500          something
```

Now in the above table a few records are missing and if I write

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <tr>
     <td>
         @Html.ActionLink(item.Company_Name, "Brand", new {Company_Name=item.Company_Name})
     </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

now here I get the result as

```
Brand
Samsung  
Samsung  
Apple   
HTC
HTC
Nokia
```

I want it to be as

```
Brand
Samsung      
Apple   
HTC
Nokia
```

Any ideas will be appreciated. I want the Linq to come within the view.

Comment: It might help if you showed us your query

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Plz look at the edited post.

Comment: What part of "post your query" don't you understand?  FYI, it's bad practice to put Linq in your view in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Distinct() on that Property:

```
@foreach (var companyName in Model.Select(m => m.Company_Name).Distinct())
{
<tr>                   
         //Anything extra could be added here to check the duplicate values
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(companyName, "Brand", 
         new { Company_Name = companyName })
    </td>  
</tr
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about Grouping them on `Company_Name`:

```
@{

var grouped = Model.GroupBy(x=>x.Company_Name);
}
@foreach (var item in grouped)
{
<tr>                   
         //Anything extra could be added here to check the duplicate values
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Key"Brand", 
         new { Company_Name = item.Key })
    </td>  
</tr
 }
```